# Converting a hash from Java to Javascript

Tags: java, node.js, react-native, encryption, cryptojs

I'm trying to convert a hash function originally written in Java to Javascript in our codebase. However, I am getting different results.
Below is the code in Java

```
public static String hashText(String str) {
    MessageDigest messageDigest;
    try {
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        messageDigest = null;
    }
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        messageDigest.update(bytes);
        bytes = messageDigest.digest();
    }
    hashedText = new String(Base64.encode(bytes, 2));
    return hashedText.replace(StringUtils.LF, "");
}
```

And here is what I wrote in Javascript

```
function hashText(text){
  const crypto = require('crypto')
  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
  const digest = hash.update(text).digest();
  return digest.toString("base64")
}
console.log(hashText(text))
```

I've been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here but no success yet. I need help!

Comment: That `for` loop in the java, it looks like it's rehashing the hash 64 times. Looks like you're only hashing once in javascript.

Comment: Your `Base64.encode(byte[],int)` in Java does not match either the `java.util` one or Apache commons-codec, so if it does anything weird (I don't say nonstandard because there isn't a definite standard for base64), the nodejs version of base64 may not match it without help.

Comment: What is Java's "default character encoding" on your system? Some ISO-8859 variant? Some Windows code page? UTF-8? The results of 'str.getBytes()' depend on that default. Second point: it would help to provide some example inputs and expected/differing outputs.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff the default is UTF-8. I've been able to solve it, and have posted the answer in case anyone else needs it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the way nodejs crypto hash copy works is kinda different. As stated in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash), it creates a new Hash object that contains a deep copy of the internal state of the current Hash object. However, what I need is to create a new hash with the encoded string.

Below is a sample of a working snippet

```
function hashText(text, length) {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  let digest = text;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    hash.update(digest);
    digest = hash.digest();
  }

  return digest.toString('base64');
}
console.log(hashText(text, 64));
```

Thanks to everyone that helped one way or the other

Answer (score 2):

That for loop in the java, it looks like it's rehashing the hash 64 times. Looks like you're only hashing once in JavaScript. Here's an example of how you might do that loop in node.js.

```
function hashText(text, iter = 1) {
  const crypto = require('crypto');
  let digest = text;
  for (let i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    digest = hash.update(digest).digest();
  }
  return digest.toString('base64');
}
const text = 'asdf 1234 zxcv 5678';
console.log(hashText(text, 64));
```

*Edit: I don't use java, didn't know how [MessageDigest.digest()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest--), worked. Specifically:

> ... The digest is reset after this call is made.

In node, this means running `createHash` every iteration of the loop. Thanks @dave_thompson_085 for pointing this out!

Comment: You're right nodejs hashes can't be recycled like Java's, but doing the `copy` _after_ `update` gives the wrong result. Make the loop body  `digest = hash.copy().update(digest).digest();`  -- or `digest = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(digest).digest();` with no pre-create.

Comment: @David784, I just tried your answer, it is not correct. I'm still getting different results

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, edited my answer based on your correction.